# GAE modules: ImportError: No module named model

Tags: python, google-app-engine

HI I playing with GAE modules and found this error:

```
ImportError: No module named model
```

My project tree is this:

```
|-- api
|    |-- __init__.py
|    |-- user_api.py
|    |-- api.yaml
|-- panel
|    |-- __init__.py
|    |-- panel.py
|    |-- panel.yaml
|-- __init__.py
|-- model.py
|-- dispatch.yaml
```

My idea was to have in `model.py` defined all model classes and the import it to use it on the different modules.

model.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb


class MyUser(ndb.Model):
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    password = ndb.StringProperty()
```

user_api.py:

```
import os.path
import sys
import logging

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), os.pardir))

from model import MyUser

@endpoints.api(name='user', version='v1')
class UserApi(remote.Service):
    . . .
```

Is it possible? Is it a good practice?

Thanks

Comment: The application root should already be on `sys.path`, and so you shouldn't need to modify it.  I just did a quick test with `./model.py`, `./api/__init__.py`, and `./api/user_api.py`, with an `app.yaml` that pointed to a WSGI app that imported `user_api`, and it worked.

Comment: Hi Dan the docs for GAE modules does not mention ann app.yaml at root level

Comment: If you're using modules, `app.yaml` is just the config file for the default module.  A specific module would have the same material in its own config file, whatever you named it.  This would include, among other things, the handler definitions that map URLs to WSGI apps (or in the case of endpoints, the `endpoints.api_server()`).

Comment: Regardless, the app root directory should be on the `sys.path`.  The problem may be related to the Python import rules for modules and packages.  You have `__init__.py` files in place so I'm not sure what you'd need to change.

Comment: Well, finally I ended out moving copying model.py to api folder. This is not the best approach as I will have to copy mannualy every time the model changes